# How to execute multiple commands in a Docker container and leave the shell session open?

Tags: docker

I have a running Docker container and need to start and interactive shell session inside the container and execute multiple commands inside before this.
How can I do that?

I tried

```sh
docker exec -it foo bash < my_commands_to_exexute_inside_the_container.sh
```

and

```sh
docker run foo bash -c "echo Foo;echo Bar"
```

But none of this works. The first one does not execute the commands from the script and the second one does this, but closes the terminal session.

Any idea?
Btw: The commands should come from outside the container. There is not file in the container with those commands.

Edit:

The following does almost exactly what I want it. The only catch is that the first command closes the shell and the second command opens it again. This causes me to lose environment variables.

```sh
docker exec -i foo bash < "cli.sh"
docker exec -it foo bash
```

Is there any way to achieve this behavior **without** closing the shell in between?

Comment: What's the main process the container is running?  If that process weren't inside a container, how would you get an interactive shell inside the process?

Comment: I do not understand your question, sry.

Answer (score 0):

Drop the `-t` in your first command (you're running a script, not interacting with the shell prompt manually, so you don't need to allocate a TTY):

```
docker exec -i foo bash < my_commands_to_exexute_inside_the_container.sh
```

For example, if I start up a Fedora container:

```
docker run -d --name shell fedora:34 sleep inf
```

And I have a file `mycommands.sh` with the following content:

```
echo "The time is $(date)"
echo "This system is: $(uname -a)"
```

I can execute that shell in the container like this:

```
$ docker exec -i shell bash < mycommands.sh
The time is Sat Jul 31 12:37:59 UTC 2021
This system is: Linux 50715db46e9b 5.12.14-300.fc34.x86_64 #1 SMP Wed Jun 30 18:30:21 UTC 2021 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! But this will close the interactive shell session. If I execute this, I will end up outside the container. How can I keep the shell inside the container open?

Comment: I'm not entirely clear what your goal is here. The container will continue running, so whatever command you used in your `docker run` command will continue running. I've used `sleep inf` here, but you could instead start an interactive shell, although that doesn't make much sense (I guess you could `docker attach` to it). How would you accomplish this if Docker wasn't involved? With most shells, either (a) you start an interactive session, or (b) you pass in commands on stdin and the shell exits when it finished executing the script.

Comment: @DarkMath I believe you could [bind mount](https://docs.docker.com/storage/bind-mounts/) the shell script file into the container, then run `docker exec -it runningContainer bash` and execute that file once you're inside. After that, the bash prompt would just sit there indefinitely, waiting for you.

Comment: @DarkMath Be aware that containers can't stay up for no reason. They can't just sit there, doing nothing. A container is meant to execute something, like, say, a web server process. If it's not doing anything, it simply exits.

Answer (score 0):

What about this?

```
docker run -it alpine sh -c "pwd;date;sh"
```